# SitecoreEventArgs Result.Cancel = true not Canceling the event

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

In the sitecore `Content Editor` I want to cancel the adding of an item.So I used the `Event Handler` `item:added`and wrote a method to cancel the event.. But its now working, I have spending so much effort but no clue.

Here is the code:

```csharp
 public void MoreThenOneAddressAllowed(object sender, EventArgs args)
 {
     var item = Event.ExtractParameter<Item>(args, 0);

     if (item.TemplateID.ToString() == Settings.GetSetting("AddressEntryTemplateID"))
     {
        if (item.Parent.Fields["More than one address allowed"] != null && item.Parent.Fields["More than one address allowed"].Value != "1" && item.Parent.Children.Count >= 1)
        {
            SitecoreEventArgs evt = args as SitecoreEventArgs;
            evt.Result.Cancel = true;
            Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Alert("More than one address not allowed under this item!!");
        }
     }   
 }
```

Here the entry in the configuration file:

```xml
 <event name="item:added">
        <handler type="EventHandlers.CompanyEventHandler" method="MoreThenOneAddressAllowed" />
      </event>
```

I can see the message in the content editor. But the item is also added, some how I want to stop the adding of item.

Comment: Isn't the added event too late? You could try looking into the item:creating event as this will occur earlier.

Comment: As @goldengrahams wrote, `item:added` event is executed when the item is already created. It is too late.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `item:creating` event as this will occur earlier.
`item:added` will be too late!

Answer (score 5):

Not sure why, exactly. But you should maybe consider implementing this rule as an Insert Rule instead. Only give editors the "Insert Address" option dynamically on elements that do not have one already.

For an example on how that could be set up, see here: http://www.newguid.net/sitecore/2011/sitecore-rules-engine-how-to-create-an-insert-option-rule/

Comment: @Mark Cassidy answer is valid. You just need to have proper condition that will check if additional child items are allowed.

Comment: @Mark Cassidy: With this solution, when there is no item in the 'Folder' then the insert option will not work.